# Select random X (or top X) from the table dynamically based on another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

table 1

| client | how_many_to_pick |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 3 |

table 2

| client | data |
| --- | --- |
| a | a123 |
| a | a234 |
| a | a345 |
| a | a456 |
| b | b123 |
| b | b234 |
| b | b345 |
| b | b456 |
| c | c123 |
| c | c234 |
| c | c345 |
| c | c456 |

I want to select random `X` (or maybe if it’s simpler, top `X`) rows from table 2, while X is `how_many_to_pick` from the first table.

In that example above, the output should be

| client | data |
| --- | --- |
| a | a123 |
| a | a234 |
| b | b123 |
| c | c123 |
| c | c234 |
| c | c345 |

If X is the same number for all clients, I'd use `row_number() over partition` to create incremental number as index and pick the rows where the index <= X, but I don't know how to do it if X is different for every client?

I'm doing this in BigQuery.

Comment: Seems, your ``X`` is not random. X=how_many_to_pick. Show your query, where ``X is the same number for all clients``.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways based on your description: (which is not really random but the row count is present somewhere.)

```
with table1 as (
    select 'a' as client, 2 as how_many_to_pick
    union all 
    select 'b' as client, 1 as how_many_to_pick
),
table2 as (
    select 'a' as client,   'a123' as data
    union all 
    select 'a' as client,   '234' as data
    union all 
    select 'a' as client,   'a345' as data
    union all 
    select 'a' as client,   'a456' as data
    union all 
    select 'b' as client,   'b123' as data
    union all 
    select 'b' as client,   'b234' as data
    union all 
    select 'b' as client,   'b345' as data
)
   
select t2.client, t2.data 
from (select *, row_number() over(partition by client order by data) as rnk 
      from table2
     ) as t2 
join table1 as t1 
    on t1.client = t2.client 
where  t2.rnk <= t1.how_many_to_pick
```

Here you can use where as shown above OR you can also try:

```
on t1.client = t2.client and  t2.rnk <= t1.how_many_to_pick
```

in either case, it will give you what you need:

[image]